# dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libhidapi-libusb.so" not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, libusb

I am having a hard time trying to install this library into Android Studio. I am trying to use a library for a NFC reader and it seems that I need to install this native library but I am having a lot of difficulties. I already tried to look up solutions online but nothing seems to have worked. From what I have read, I need to use JNI and NDK to create the file but I haven't been able to do that. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if there is any other information that I could provide that would help.

I tried uploading the hid.c file and the Android.mk file (I got from their github) to the JNI folder. I installed NDK for Android Studio. I edited the necessary files to link the library such as build.gradle and gradle.properties. There was no .so file created and I am still getting an error when I try to run my app.

Comment: You need to add some more details like your CMakeLists.txt etc.